# visual basic "programming language" msg box wont display all of the array

Tags: vb.net, project

Im working on a basic "programming language" in Visual basic and i have a command called "print", so you can type something like print "hello world", except if i was to run that it would just say "hello", i want it so it will display anything written after print and not just the first word, here is the code :

```
    Private Sub RunToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RunToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox1.Lines)
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim testString As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i)
            Dim testArray() As String = Split(testString)

            If testArray(0) = "print" Then
                MsgBox(testArray(1))

            End If

            If testArray(0) = "beep" Then
                Beep()
            End If

            If testArray(0) = "exit" Then
                End
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the rest on and show that:

```
MsgBox(String.Join(" ", testArray.Skip(1))
```

You will also need to make sure `System.Linq` is an imported namespace.